# How to calculate leap years from just provided age?

Tags: javascript, function

**Easy function to get the number of leap years and also get array of those years**

For both variable you can change values to get a different result

**currentAge = 80;
let deathYear = 2010**

```js
// Simple passing age you will get  leap years array and number of years
let currentAge = 80;
let deathYear = 2010

function getLeapYears(currentAge,deathYear){
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear() 
    let getBirthYear = 0 
    if(deathYear){
        getBirthYear = deathYear-currentAge
    }
    else{
        getBirthYear = currentYear-currentAge
    }
    
    let numberOfYears = []
    for(let index = getBirthYear; index<currentYear+1;index++ ){
    numberOfYears.push(index)
    }
    
    let leapYears = []
    leapYears= numberOfYears.filter(item => item % 4 ==0)
    return {
        leapYears:leapYears,
        numberOfYears:leapYears.length +1
    }
    
}

// Simple passing age you will get  leap years array and number of years
const result1 = getLeapYears(currentAge)
const result2 = getLeapYears(currentAge,deathYear)
console.log("result1",  result1)
console.log("result2",  result2)
```

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Comment: (Well aside from, possibly, the fact that your leap year predicate is not correct, though it won't affect any years until 2100.)